# Duda funcionamiento de las TRANSACIONES SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, transacciones

Estoy intentando entender como funciona:

Tenemos esto

```
Session1 BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ SERIALIZABLE;
Session1 SELECT * FROM objects;
id | name | value
-------------+---------------------+-----------
1 | Object 1 | 10
2 | Object 2 | 5
3 | Object 3 | 3
4 | Object 4 | 20
(4 rows)
Session2 UPDATE objects SET value = 3 WHERE id = 1;
Session1 SELECT * FROM objects;
.....
```

En este caso el El ultimo SELECT no veria el cambio ya que no se ha ejecutado al intentar hacer el UPDATE sin el COMMIT de la primera sesion. (Por el READ SERIALIZABLE)

CASO2

```
Session1 BEGIN TRANSACTION;
Session1 SELECT * FROM objects;
id | name | value
-------------+---------------------+-----------
1 | Object 1 | 10
2 | Object 2 | 5
3 | Object 3 | 3
4 | Object 4 | 20
(4 rows)
Session2 BEGIN TRANSACTION;
Session2 UPDATE objects SET value = 1 WHERE id = 1;
Session2 COMMIT;
Session1 SELECT * FROM objects;
.....
Session1 COMMIT;
```

En este caso el ultimo SELECT (realizado por sesion1) veria el cambio que ha hecho sesion2 ya que al no tener parametros de tipos de lectura ni se ha serializado se irian ejecutando?

Es asi o lo estoy entendiendo mal.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. El tema de tu duda se llama _"Nivel de aislamiento de la transacción"_, en Inglés, _["Transaction Isolation Level"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html)_. Es un tema bien documentado y, en su forma actual, me temo que la respuesta es demasiado larga para el formato del sitio. Te recomiendo leer la documentación que enlacé, donde creo que está bien explicado el tema.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es una duda de concepto no basada en una situación real, la respuesta sería demasiado amplia para el formato de SO.